# Sequentially assign rows of one data frame to empty data frames of varying rows, until all positions within empty data frame are filled

Tags: r, algorithm, dataframe, sequence, subset

I'm a completely novice to R, and I haven't been able to figure this out. I've spent hours trying to do this, with no luck. I am trying to do the following.

- I have a data frame, **df_main**, with 25 rows, rank ordered.
- I have 3 empty data frames, each of which are of a varying number of rows (**df_1** = 9 rows, **df_2** = 13 rows, **df_3** = 3 rows).

I want to assign the rows of df_main to df_1, df_2, and df_3 sequentially, until each data frame has the correct number of rows in it. Meaning:

- Row 1 of df_main is assigned to df_1
- Row 2 of df_main is assigned to df_2
- Row 3 of df_main is assigned to df_3
- Row 4 of df_main is assigned to df_1
- Row 5 of df_main is assigned to df_2
- and so on...

Thus, df_1 (9 rows) should have the following rows or df_main [1, 4, 7, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20], df_2 (13 rows) should have the following rows of df_main [2, 5, 8, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25], and df_3 (3 rows) should have the following rows of df_main [3, 6, 9].

I don't know where to start, so I have no code to show. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try something like this, can be simplified more but this way more transparent:

```
I <- rbind(
   cbind(rep("df_1",nrow(df_1)),
      1:nrow(df_1)),
   cbind(rep("df_2",nrow(df_2)),
      1:nrow(df_2)),
   cbind(rep("df_3",nrow(df_3)),
      1:nrow(df_3)))
I <- I [order(I[,2],I[,1]),]
df_main <- cbind(df_main, I[1:nrow(df_main),])
```

, and now you can easily extract the rows into the separate dfs:

```
df_1 <- df_main [df_main$v1 == "df_1",]
```

I had no chance to test this code, but I hope it helps to get closer to the solution.

,David.

*Edit:*

Hi Nathan, I guess it depends a little bit on how the n_1 empty data frames present themselves. In the end, the only info you need from the empty data frames is there number of rows (unless not each row is allowed to hold the new data). If you have that number of rows for each it is easier to actually create the empty data frames:

First, simulate some data:

```
n <- 2000
n_1 <- 20

df_main <- data.frame ( SomeCol = paste ( "Some Value", 1:n ))
```

Create fake rowcounts the empty dfs:

```
(rowcounts_of_n_1_dfs <- round ( rnorm ( n_1, 75, 25 )))
```

**not run start**

In case you would actually have to start from objects df_1, df_2, .., df_, then you can do this:

```
rowcounts_of_n_1_dfs <- unlist ( lapply ( 1:n_1, function ( x ){
  return ( nrow ( get ( paste ( "df", x, sep = "_" ))))
}))
```

**not run end**

Now create the distributionlist as simply as:

```
dist <- data.frame ( df = rep ( 1:n_1, rowcounts_of_n_1_dfs ),
                  i = unlist ( lapply ( rowcounts_of_n_1_dfs, seq )))
```

The magic is in the sort:

```
dist <- dist [ with ( dist, order( i, df )),]
```

Only need to distribute until df_main is used up so:

```
df_list <- split ( df_main, dist$df [ 1:nrow ( df_main )] )
```

Finally, place the dataframes in global environment:

```
dummy <- lapply ( 1:n_1, function ( x ) {
  assign ( paste ( "df", x, sep = "_" ), df_list [[ x ]], envir = globalenv ())
})
```

Check whether the data frame have been created:

```
ls()
```

I get this:

```
[1] "df_1"                 "df_10"                "df_11"                "df_12"                "df_13"                "df_14"               
[7] "df_15"                "df_16"                "df_17"                "df_18"                "df_19"                "df_2"                
[13] "df_20"                "df_3"                 "df_4"                 "df_5"                 "df_6"                 "df_7"                
[19] "df_8"                 "df_9"                 "df_list"              "df_main"              "dist"                 "dummy"               
[25] "n"                    "n_1"                  "rowcounts_of_n_1_dfs"
```

Comment: Hi David, this does exactly what I needed it to do. Thanks! One more question. Is there a more programmatic answer? That is, let's say I had one df_main with n rows from which I need to distribute rows in the same fashion as described above to n_1 data frames each with some number of rows. How would you do this?

Comment: Hi Nathan, I guess it depends a little bit on how the n_1 empty data frames present themselves. In the end, the only info you need from the empty data frames is there number of rows (unless not each row is allowed to hold the new data). See update of my answer.

Comment: Awesome, David! Thanks so much for this. You've been incredibly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This bit of modulo arithmetic will give you a possible category id for the rows:

```
> 1+ 0:24 %% 3
 [1] 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1
```

Although you didn't offer a worked example this code *might* be effective in giving a useful result:

```
df <-  cbind(df, catvar= 1+ 0:24 %% 3)
df_list <- split( df , df$catvar)
```

Comment: Thanks for this but this doesn't account for the fact that each sub data frame is of differing number of rows.